# Beginner licensing mode error Ansys student version

Tags: simulation

I am an undergraduate student new to Ansys and would like to import a PCB design into Ansys to do some simulations. I get this error when attempting to import a .zip into the workspace:

```
Global - Messages
  [error] Control File Translation: Cannot checkout Elec_Solve_1 and elec_solve_level2(Invalid license mode).
```

How do I resolve this? Also, the manual said it should accept .step files but I don't see the option to import .step in the student version which I downloaded.

Comment: why did you use the `electromagnetism` tag? ... your qiestion is about a software license

Comment: Given how much Ansys likely costs your school, you really should go to Ansys support first. Your tuition literally pays for this stuff. Then you can post an answer to your own question (yes, it's encouraged - post it as an answer, not as a comment or a question edit), helping other people out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use that program but it is very common for student versions to have limited capabilities.

The error message is actually better than most- it says you don't have the right license for that function.